# Platform.environment not available in Dart

Tags: dart, environment-variables

If I have the Dart program:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final keyEnv = Platform.environment['KEY'];
  const keyString = String.fromEnvironment('KEY');
  print('keyEnv: $keyEnv');
  print('keyString: $keyString');
}
```

And run it like so:

```bash
dart run --define=KEY=hello bin/main.dart
```

This is the result:

```
keyEnv: null
keyString: hello
```

Why is the `KEY` variable not available from `Platform.environment`? What can I do to access it? I'm testing this on a Mac with Dart 3.3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Platform.environment` is for reading the *system*'s environment variables.  They're what other programming languages typically refer to as environment variables.  These environment variables would typically include things such as `PATH`, `HOSTNAME`, `USER`, etc.

For example, in `bash` (or with many other shells for POSIX systems), you'd typically do:

```bash
$ KEY=hello dart bin/main.dart
```

or

```bash
$ export KEY=hello
$ dart bin/main.dart
```

On Windows, you'd do:

```
> set KEY=hello
> dart bin/main.dart
```

or set the environment variable from the Advanced System Settings control panel applet.

This is different the "compilation configuration environment" that `String.fromEnvironment`, `bool.fromEnvironment`, etc. read from.  Note [the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/String.fromEnvironment.html):

> The compilation configuration environment is provided by the surrounding tools which are compiling or running the Dart program.
>
> ...
>
> The compilation configuration environment is not the same as the environment variables of a POSIX process. Those can be accessed on native platforms using `Platform.environment` from the `dart:io` library.