# Setting and accessing environment variables in Dart Globe

Tags: dart, environment-variables, dart-globe

I'm trying to set an environment variable on the [Globe](https://globe.dev) platform for Dart server apps.

To isolate the problem I created the following Shelf server app:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

final _router = Router()..get('/', _rootHandler);

Response _rootHandler(Request req) {
  final keyEnv = Platform.environment['KEY'];
  const keyString = String.fromEnvironment('KEY');
  print('keyEnv: $keyEnv');
  print('keyString: $keyString');
  return Response.ok('keyEnv: $keyEnv\nkeyString: $keyString');
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;
  final handler =
      Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router.call);
  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');
  final server = await serve(handler, ip, port);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
}
```

Running locally on a Mac like so:

```
# terminal 1
dart run --define=KEY=hello bin/server.dart

# terminal 2
curl http://localhost:8080
```

I get this result in terminal 1:

```
Server listening on port 8080
keyEnv: null
keyString: hello
```

This is consistent with [my related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78111631/platform-environment-not-available-in-dart).

I then deployed [the GitHub version of my test app](https://github.com/suragch/globe_test) on Globe and set the environment variable like so:

[image]

However, when I access [the Globe deployed version](https://globe-test-ifxs6va-suragch.globeapp.dev/), this is the response:

```
keyEnv: null
keyString:
```

Why is the `KEY` environment variable not available anywhere? How can I access it? The [Globe documentation](https://docs.globe.dev/deployments/environment-variables) indicates that I should be able to use `Platform.environment`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

#### Update:

Here is my **Settings -> Environment Variables** setup in Globe:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-platform_platform/Platform/environment.html.

***The returned environment is an unmodifiable map whose content is retrieved from the operating system on its first use.***

I don't think you can modify it directly.

I have printed my own `Platform.environment`. I think you can append `export KEY=hello`   to your .zshrc file. Or execute `export KEY=hello` in your terminal. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is useful when you want to define a compile-time constant:

```
# terminal 1
dart run --define=KEY=hello bin/server.dart

// Use like this
String.fromEnvironment('KEY')
```

But when using environment variables, the syntax is different:

```
# terminal 2
KEY=<value> dart run bin/server.dart

// Use like this
Platform.environment['KEY']
```

When setting up environment variables with a hosting provider like Globe or Vercel, you'll want to use the second variant.

Comment: In Globe, I have an option to specify the `main` function file (`bin/server.dart`) and also a location to enter a key and a value, but I didn't see a place to input something like `KEY=<value> dart run bin/server.dart`.

Comment: Once you created a Globe project, go to Settings -> Environment Variables -> Add Variable